# Coldfusion displays 0E-20 Instead of a Zero

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I have developed an RIA for a company's external sales force where they can view relevant information regarding thier customers before a site visit.

The data resides in SQL and is set to default to zero if any of the values are NULL. For example

```
(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL( FMS2.NotDueLCY, 0)), 0) AS NotDueLCY
FROM dbo.FLEX_BalanceOverdue AS FMS2        
WHERE 
FMS2.ShipToCode LIKE @ShipToCode 
AND 
FMS2.Customer LIKE @Customer 
AND 
FMS2.SalesPersonCode LIKE @SalesPerson) AS NotDueLCY
```

If this query is Executed the data looks correct. This query is in a Stroed Procedure. I then use coldfusion to inoke these SP's

If it is executed using CF the Zero Values appear in the browser window as 0E-20 and susequently this data also appears in Flex as 0E-20

I am a bit stumped as to what is causing this. If any of you have some ideas I would be most grateful
BD :)

Comment: How do you invoke the sp? With `cfinvoke`? It worth to show some of your CFML for better understanding the possible reasons.

Comment: Well to test it I used CFInvoke but the CFC is run from a Flex Application in the Final Build. I used the CF Invoke to try and see where the 0E-20 was coming from and It seems to be generated by CF itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix this. I had to handle the fact that a NaN was hitting the Flex app when the value of data was a zero and after some thorough checking only a zero. So once that was apparent I applied a label function to the data grid displaying the data. Telling it if a NaN was in the data set display a Zero. Not solved the root of the issue but a tidy work around

Answer (score 0):

It possibly something to do with the way its coming out of your Stored Procedure. If you're using cfstoredprocedure to call your SP you could use [cfprocparam](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d52.html) to ensure that it is returning the values as the expected datatype.

If you're using CFQuery to call your SP, you'll probably need to CAST your columns on the SP side to make sure that the result is returned as the correct datatype.